# Use Javascript variable in Django Tempate

Tags: javascript, django

Before getting into the question, I know that there are a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow, but from what I've seen none has produced an answer I can use -- please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have a JavaScript variable that looks like this (this is in a `<script>` tag).

```
var html = '<img src = "{% static "img/chesspieces/wikipedia/(I guess this is the part I'm not sure about)" %}"'
```

I have another JavaScript variable called `piece` that I would like to inject like this `{{piece}}`, but can't since it's a JavaScript variable, and not a Django variable.

A lot of answers to similar questions seem to recommend making a view and calling it every time I want to access the `piece` variable, but I don't think that has any chance of working in my situation, as it would lead to the `Too Many Requests` error.

Comment: I apologize in advance, but I won't be able to be active on this question for the next 8 or so hours -- have to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing it dynamically, can't you set it up in advance? There's not a huge overhead in doing static lookups.

```
var html = ""
var pieceDict = new Object();
pieceDict['king'] ='<img src = "{% static "img/chesspieces/wikipedia/king.gif" %}"'>
pieceDict['queen'] = '<img src = "{% static "img/chesspieces/wikipedia/queen.gif" %}"'>

...    
piece = "king"
html = pieceDict[piece]
```

Comment: I can't try this now, but I see no reason why it won't work. Just out of curiosity, would there be a way of doing things dynamically?

Comment: Not without adding complexity.  The template is evaluated before the page is delivered to the browser,  and the javascript runs after,  inside the browser,  so to get the server to do an any more work,  you need to reestablish contact with it,  via ajax or another pageload,  and handle the returned info. That might be worthwhile for,  say, a search through 100s of options,  but if you only have a few possibilities,  then pre-evaluating is both more efficient and simpler.

Comment: I see, thank you very much. I'll accept the answer the question as soon as I get a chance to implement it.